# How to add GroupName to ControlTemplate for RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Style defined for a RadioButton which includes a ControlTemplate made up of BulletDecorator, VisualStateManager and Triggers.  I currently have my GroupName defined on the RadioButton in the XAML code.

The selection of a radio button when running the code is not mutually exclusive.

I have read other posts saying that the problem is a second RadioButton defined in the ControlTemplate.  I do not have a second RadioButton defined.

Here is a picture of buttons selected which should be mutually exclusive:

[image]

Here is my style:

```
 <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <BulletDecorator>
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Height, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinHeight="15" MinWidth="15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse Name="EllipseMain"
                                     Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                     Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                     Fill="Transparent"
                                     StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                     Stroke="DimGray"/>
                            <Ellipse Name="CheckMark"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     Opacity="0"
                                     Fill="#029cc7"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet> 
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="LightGray" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="LightGray" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnChecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="EllipseMain" Property="Fill" Value="#55029cc7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="EllipseMain" Property="Stroke" Value="#88029cc7"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the XAML:

```
 <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Normal" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  GroupName="gpHeadingMode" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
 <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Weather Vane" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  GroupName="gpHeadingMode" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

Tried this as a work around (in XAML):

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Normal" Content="Normal" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" GroupName="gpHeadingMode1"
                    Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                     IsChecked="{Binding HeadingModeChecked, ElementName=HeadingDialog, Converter={StaticResource RbCheckedConverter}, ConverterParameter=Normal, FallbackValue=False}" 
                     Click="RbHeadingMode_Click"/>
<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="WeatherVane" Content="Weather Vane" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" GroupName="gpHeadingMode2" 
                    Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                     IsChecked="{Binding HeadingModeChecked, ElementName=HeadingDialog, Converter={StaticResource RbCheckedConverter}, ConverterParameter=WeatherVane, FallbackValue=False}" 
                     Click="RbHeadingMode_Click"/>
```

In RbHeadingMode_Click, the dependency object HeadingModeChecked is set with the value of RadioButton.Name.  If I remove the "Style" the converter fires and does the job of toggling the IsClicked value.

Unfortunately, with the Style, the converter does not fire.

***Now the question becomes, how can I bind the IsChecked property in XAML to the Style?***

**Note: Actually, the converter does fire with Style specified but the change to IsChecked in XAML has no effect on the RadioButton.**

Comment: FYI: on MSDN: This property (GroupName) cannot be set by themes or style sheet themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove the following code from the Style and it works:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
       <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
       </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="UnChecked">
       <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
       </Storyboard>
     </VisualState>
     <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
       <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Gray" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        </Storyboard>
     </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

**Note:  Not only does the converter work on the IsChecked property but now I can remove that converter and just use Groupname to achieve mutual exclusion on the radiobuttons!**